# How to add code logic inside @Url.Action()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
location.href = '@Url.Action("PageIndex","Home",new {id = ViewBag.swfLoc })';
```

Above code snippet is resides in the `<script>` tag of my razor View `*.cshtml` file.

What I ask is : Can I add some code logic in side `Url.Action` function parameter.

e.g

```
 location.href = '@Url.Action("PageIndex","Home",new {id = ViewBag.swfLoc.isEmpty() ? "other" : "this" })';
```

Other than declare a variable inside top razor block `@{}` because I don't want to declare many dummy variables.

If possible, how? Use string of C# or JS string for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes you can. Your sample is the right way. Have you test that?

Comment: Why not just set the value of `ViewBag.swfLoc` to either `"other"` or `"this"`?

Comment: because its a method. still, another get {} property would do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works you have to just **check for null value**:

```
location.href = '@Url.Action("PageIndex", "Home", new { id = (ViewBag.swfLoc == null || ViewBag.swfLoc.isEmpty()) ? "other" : "this" })';
```